# How to disable a navigation from the url in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

**I want to disable the navigation from a page to another using URL ! I want to move from a page to another only if the form of this page is valid that's mean the navigation is allowed only using buttons in each page and not directly from the url**

This is the module.ts that encapsulate all my components :

```
const routes : Routes =  [{
 path: '',
  component: NewIntakeComponent,
children: [
 {
    path: 'generalInfo',
    loadChildren: () => import('./general-info/general-info.module').then(m => m.GeneralInfoModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'partyInfo',
    loadChildren: () => import('./party-info/party-info.module').then(m => m.PartyInfoModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'policyInfo',
    loadChildren: () => import('./policy-info/policy-info.module').then(m => m.PolicyInfoModule),
  },
  {
  path: 'uploadFiles',
  loadChildren: () => import('./files-upload/files-upload.module').then(m => m.FilesUploadModule),
  },
 {
 path: 'summaryInfo',
 loadChildren: () => import('./summary-info/summary-info.module').then(m => m.SummaryInfoModule),
 },
 {
 path: 'planningInfo',
 loadChildren: () => import('./planning-info/planning-info.module').then(m => m.PlanningInfoModule),
 },
 {
 path: 'repairdamageInfo',
 loadChildren: () => import('./repairdamage-info/repairdamage-info.module').then(m => 
 m.RepairdamageInfoModule),
 }
],
}]

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class NewIntakeRoutingModule { }
```

What should I add to disable the navigation from the url ?

Comment: A bit unclear what you want. Do you want to prevent users from going directly to an a path (/planningInfo)? What should happen if a user goes there directly?

Comment: yes I don't want the user to go directly to this page for example (/planning) without validate the previous steps ! That's why I want to disable the navigation from url

Answer (score 0):

To prevent url changes use the following in your template

```
<a routerLink="/start" skipLocationChange="true">Start</a>
```

and the following when inside a ".ts" file

```
router.navigate(['/start'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

and to prevent the direct navigation via url add the following option to your NgModule inside your routeSettings

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes), { initialNavigation: false }],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**Edit:**
Property has changed to:
`initialNavigation: 'disabled'`

Comment: this is not working , it gives me the error `Type '{ initialNavigation: false; }' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.`

Comment: im sorry, it seems like it has changed to `initialNavigation: 'disabled'`

Comment: it gives me this error `Cannot find name 'initialNavigation'`